# document styles are bleeding into injected popup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, emotion

First of all I have searched various posts on here and nothing is working. Defining `all: initial` or `all: unset` does nothing. I have tried shadowDOM as well but styles are still bleeding into that. Currently I'm using emotion for my styles that prefixes everything with my app name to make everything unique. On majority of websites everything works fine, but some websites like stackoverflow targets the `body, html` for font-sizes which seem to bleed into my injected popup.

This is my inject.js file which where I injected the element into the websites DOM

```
import App from './App'

const ExtensionApp = styled.div`
  font-size: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 320px;
  z-index: 2147483647;
`

const Index = () => {
  return (
   <ExtensionApp>
    <App />
   </ExtensionApp>
 )
}

  const rootElement = document.createElement('div')
  rootElement.id = 'myApp-extension-root'
  const root = document.body.appendChild(rootElement)

  const stylesElement = document.createElement('div')
  stylesElement.id = 'myApp-extension-styles'
  const styles = document.body.appendChild(stylesElement)

  const myCache = createCache({
    key: 'myApp',
    container: styles
  })

ReactDOM.render(
  <CacheProvider value={myCache}>
    <Index/>
  </CacheProvider>, root)
```

Now I have tried to put those styles on the root id `myApp-extension-root` but still nothing. I am just so lost and I don't understand how to fix this problem. The only solution I found was to wrap it in an Iframe but I had trouble making the iframe grow to its content, it would simply stay the same width/height no matter what I did. So iframe is the last resort for me.

Edit:

Inspecting the div that is wrapping the span to have `3rem` as font-size, the computed size is 39px

- 3rem !important .myApp-riwa84
- <s>100%</s> html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video
- <s>16px</s> .myApp-1na1ypp
- <s>13px</s> html, body

Under styles for this span

- <s>font-size: 16px;</s>
- position: fixed;
- right: 10px;
- top: 15px;
- width: 320px;
- z-index: 2147483647;
- <s>font-family: Montserrat, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;</s>

The span itself has

```
.myApp-riwa84 {
    all: initial !important;
    font-size: 3rem !important;
}
```

Comment: You can add all: unset !important to each of your CSS selectors or use an iframe and send a message to the content script each time you need to resize.

Comment: Shouldnt doing that for the root ID be equivalent to selection everything within that ID? @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: You are correct, it should indeed be inherited, but seems like it should be set to initial, not unset. Have you tired all: initial !important ?

Comment: So I have this as a test, `<Text size='3rem'>font size test</Text>` and the styles for this is `export const Text = styled.span(props => ({
  all: 'initial !important',
  fontSize: `${props.size} !important`
}))` Sites other than stackoverflow show font size as 48px, while stackoverflow shows 39px. And its because stackoverflow targets `html, body` that has a font-size value of 13px. I cannot override this for some reason. @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: There is something wrong, if you are explicitly setting the font-size on your element you shouldn't even need to clear the body style. Have you check what you're getting in the inspector? if you copied the output HTML to your post it'd make it more clear

Comment: What do you mean by output HTML? What is compiled when I build it? Its not even used for the most part if I use `emotion`, if I don't use `emotion` It does need to be used due to me having to link the css files. The popup.html `<head><link href="/css/extension.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><div id="popup"></div><script src="/js/extension.js"></script>` @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: Yes, I mean when you see your text is of the wrong size can you inspect it (DOM and calculated CSS). Because if I just add a div to the stackoverflow container element I have to problem styling it.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I edited my post, hopefully that helps, but its a bit confusing to me because stackoverflows `html, body` `font-size: 13px;` is crossed out, but if i uncheck that, my font size becomes 48px as it should be.

Comment: Seems like I have to use pixels, and it works. Using rem on stackoverflow just gets adjusted to something else for some reason, which seems to be only on a few sites like this.

Comment: Ah, yes, you use rem which is proportionate to font-size, so your styles get proportionate to the parent container font-size. That makes total sense. I guess you solved your problem now?

Comment: I mean sort of, I just don't understand why my root ID is not the parent element. What i mean is even if I try something like this `<div style={{ fontSize: '16px' }}>
      <Text size='3rem'>font size test</Text>
    </div>`

This rem font size results in 39pixels instead of 48 pixels because of the `html, body` being a font-size of 13px for overstackflow. So the parent element is obviously not this wrapping div :/ @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: Because r in rem stands for root, try  3em instead

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Ah, so there is no way to get around that then huh, unless its in an iframe that has its own `html, body` ?

Comment: If you have to use rem, yes, you need your own body element.

Comment: To reset `all` in ShadowDOM correctly you should specify it either on `:host` rule or on the root element inside ShadowDOM.